# Issue running Postgresql 9.6 backup (pg_dump/pg_dumpall)

Tags: database, postgresql, postgresql-9.6, enterprisedb

I have a postgreSQL 9.6 installation on Ubuntu 16.04, provided by the EnterpriseDB. I've been connecting to the local server and using it for a number of months. I figured I should backup the server at this point, so I tried using the pg_dump command as follows:

1. cd to postgres bin at /opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin
2. Run pg_dump via `sudo pg_dumpall > /sata_ssd2/pgdump/0419.bkp`

This gives an error: `Error: You must install at least one postgresql-client-<version> package.` I tried installing via: `sudo apt-get install postgresql-client-9.6` but that package does not seem to exist.

I also tried to run pg_dump and pg_dumpall via pgAdmin4. It first made me fill in the binary paths for EDB Advanced Server Binary Path and PostgreSQL Binary Path; I put in  `opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/`, which is where the pg_dump executable is. When I tried to run the backups, I got the error: `'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe1 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)`. I found an answer to this elsewhere that recommended changing from `client_encoding = SQLascii` to `client_encoding = utf8` in postgresql.conf, but this did not help.

Does anyone have any advice on where to go from here?

Comment: Are PGDATA, PGHOME, and PGLOCALEDIR environment variables defined for your session?

Comment: `cd to postgres bin at /opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin` why? dont you have `/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin` in the PATH? (and do you have `.`in the path (you shouldn't)

Comment: `sudo pg_dumpall ...` You should not run as root. root is (normally) not a *postgres* user. You could attempt to run as user `postgres` instead (=the postgres superuser) The postgres user also has a big chance of having the correct PATH- and other environment-settings.

Answer (score 0):

In a unix/linux system the current directory `.` is not on the `PATH` and not searched for binaries.

If you want to run the command `pg_basebackup` in `/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/`, you run `/opt/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/pg_basebackup`.

If you did want to run the command `pg_basebackup` that you knew was in the current directory you could write `./pg_basebackup` instead. But just using the full path rather than `cd`ing unnecessarily is better.